# UIActionsheet's semi-transparent background shifting upwards after dismissing a modal view controller

Tags: ios, ios7, uikit

I'm seeing what appears to be an upward shift of the semi-transparent background of the UIActionSheet. It only happens after the action sheet is presented following a dismissal of a modal view controller. Has anyone had any experience with this? I have some screen shots of it displaying correctly and then incorrectly.

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmPZV.jpg

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvvkO.jpg

Thanks for you help!

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unsaved Changed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Overwrite" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
actionSheet.tag = 0;        
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];